# Civilization V: Other human player can't find hosted game

Tags: civilization-5

I'm trying to load a saved multiplayer game with my friend. We started yesterday and I, as the host, turned autosave so it'll save the game every turn.

I went on Multiplayer > Local Network > Host Game > Load Game and loaded the most recent autosave. My friend then on local network but could not see my game whereas on my screen, it would say that he is missing (I could either exclude him and proceed or proceed if he comes).

Do you know what might be happening?

Thanks a lot and happy gaming.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Are you asking why he can't see your server?

Answer (score 1):

Did you start a private game, those are not in the server list.
You can always invite him into your game. He then gets an invitation to join you in playing civ V in his steam chatbox.